# how to give font style in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a text  for eg: "Ram is 24 kg"

This text is coming based on some calculation. These calculation I am doing in my angularjs controller.I want to give styling for these text like "Ram is" in areal font and "24 kg" is in red color times new roman font. How can I achieve this using angularjs

In javascript we can use innerhtml. But how can i implement this in angularjs

here is my sample code

```
if(condition)
   name = $scope.somevalue1
else if(condition)
 name = $scope.somevalue2
else
 name = $scope.somevalue3

$scope.resultname = name;

if(condition)
   weight = $scope.weightvalue1
else if(condition)
  weight = $scope.somevalue2
else
  weight = $scope.somevalue3

$scope.resultname = $scope.resultname+" is"+ weight; 

if(condition)
   mess= $scope.messvalue1
else if(condition)
  mess = $scope.messvalue2
else
  mess = $scope.messvalue3

$scope.resultname = $scope.resultname+" "+ mess
```

Comment: You need to use ngSanatize, and you can set html values in scope variable. In the UI side you can use ng-bind-html to bind data with scope variable

Comment: can you please explain with example

Comment: Added code for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<span id="output"></span>
<section ng-app="myApp">
<article ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<p ng-bind-html="resultname"></p>
</article>
</section>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('controllers', []);
angular.module('myApp', ['controllers','ngSanitize']);    
angular.module('controllers').controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope){
$scope.resultname= 'Ram is <span class="myStyle">24</span>kg'
});
```

CSS

```
 .myStyle{
  color:red
 }
```

You will require ngSanatize js file

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I would make heavier use of Angular's tempting features - keep your HTML out of your JS files entirely. I've just used a controller for the sake of this example, but if this is a snippet of HTML you're going to be re-using, it belongs in a directive/component (depending on what version of Angular you're using).

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Ram';
      $scope.weight = '24';
      $scope.mess = 'kg';
    }
  ]);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.weight {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<main data-ng-app="demo">
  <div data-ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <p>{{::name}} is <span class="weight">{{::weight}} {{::mess}}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ng-style to html element.

With this directive you can set style from your controller.

Code is like this:

```
<h2 ng-style="myStyle"/>
```

And in your controller you set

```
$scope.myStyle = "{'background-color':'blue'}"
```

More information you can find in angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).